# I'm so tired I swear I can't find the issue. It seems that whenever I run the code, it prints 5426 93 17 77 31 None

Tags: python

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, node_data):
        self._data = node_data
        self._next = None
    
    def get_data(self):
        return self._data
    
    def set_data(self, node_data):
    
        self._data = node_data
    
    data = property(get_data, set_data)
    
    def get_next(self):
    
        return self._next
    
    def set_next(self, node_next):
    
        self._next = node_next
    
    next = property(get_next, set_next)
    
    def __str__(self):
    
        return str(self._data)

class UnorderedList:

    def __init__(self):
    
        self.head = None
    
    def is_empty(self):
    
        return self.head == None
    
    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp
    
    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current is not None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.next
    
        return count
    
    def search(self, item):
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            if current.data == item:
                return True
            current = current.next
    
        return False
    
    def remove(self, item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
    
        while current is not None:
            if current.data == item:
                break
            previous = current
            current = current.next
    
        if current is None:
            raise ValueError("{} is not in the list".format(item))
        if previous is None:
            self.head = current.next
        else:
            previous.next = current.next
    
    def __str__(self):
        result = " "
        n = self.head
        if n != None:
            result += str(n.data)
            n = n.next
            while n:
                result += (str(n.data) + " ")
                n = n.next
        result += " "
        return result

my_list = UnorderedList()

def main():
    thelist()

my_list.add(31)
my_list.add(77)
my_list.add(17)
my_list.add(93)
my_list.add(26)
my_list.add(54)


def thelist():
    print(my_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

what should I change when it prints, it doesn't print "5426 93 17 77 31
None"
and instead prints "54 26 93 17 77 31", so there should be a space between 54 and 26 and None is no longer there. If theres any other issues please let me know. Typing more because it says I must.sdasdasdasdasdasddasdasdsadssadasdasd

Comment: you've got representation (__repr__) if you need to show __str__ results, you need to `print(my_list)`

Comment: It doesn't print `<function thelist` at all for me. You have not added any items to the list, though.

Comment: If I run your exact code, adding `main()` as a final line (otherwise it'll do nothing), all I get is an IndentationError for your unindented docstring on line 2. If I fix that, it runs and prints nothing. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: fixed the issues mentioned.

Comment: You're still not calling `main()`.  If I add this, I get the error in your `__str__` function: `name 'node' is not defined` which refers to the `while node:` line...

Comment: I have fixed that as well.

Comment: Ok then, one thing at least is simple: to get rid of "None", don't call `print(main())`, just call `main()`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I just did it!

Comment: Please don't include spam text in your question. What it tells us is you are not willing to spend the time to ask a good question so why should we spend the time to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

> there should be a space between 54 and 26

The issue is in your `UnorderedList.__str__` method:

```
def __str__(self):
        result = " "
        n = self.head
        if n != None:
            result += str(n.data)
            n = n.next
            while n:
                result += (str(n.data) + " ")
                n = n.next
        result += " "
        return result
```

The if-statement is performing redundant, duplicate logic - and in this case it's hurting you. You're performing two consecutive string concatenations that aren't separated by whitespace. First you concatenate `"54"` from the if-statement, then `"26 "` in the first iteration of the while loop, resulting in `"5426 "`. Just get rid of the if-statement:

```
def __str__(self):
    result = ""
    node = self.head
    while node is not None:
        result += str(node.data)
        result += " "
        node = node.next
    return result
```